# ARFoundation integrated in ios native app as library crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

I built an **AR iOS** project using **ARFoundation 1.5.0**, **ARKit XR plugin 2.2.0**, with **Unity 2018.4.8f1** version and **XCode 11**.

As **standalone** iOS app it works.

Then I tried to **integrate** the Unity XCode project as *library* in an exisisting ios **native** project. The build process succeeded, but as soon as I ran the app on an iphone 7 plus device it crashed with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

The error has been raised by the **unity_init func** in *AppDelegate* class. In details the crash happens at **UnityInitRuntime** inside *the unity_init* function.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here! Did you find a solution?